Json Dinamico Java
Fala Galera, sou bem iniciante e gostaria de saber se é possível conseguir receber JSONs que varia a quantidade de colunas ou no caso keys, para manipular estes dados, estou uns 2 dias quebrando a cabeça tentando achar um meio de fazer isso e ainda não consegui, eu consegui fazer isso com os campos fixos, mas variando a quantidade ta difícil achar um meio,m e de repente me bateu a dúvida se isso seria possível devido não ser uma quantidade de colunas ou keys fixas. Se sim alguem pode me ajudar como poderia fazer isso?

Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada - basta editar a original, que é destacada para uma reavaliação).
